# Is there a way to close the stuck "Show hidden icons" without clicking an item in it?

Tags: windows-8, icons, notification-area

I'm talking about this little window on the taskbar:

[image]

It rarely gets stuck without closing (not directly reproducible) and it doesn't close unless I click on an option in it (e.g. "Customize...".

Is there a trick or just an unsolvable bug?

Comment: Justify the downvotes. Being a linux zealot does not do it.

Comment: Try and figure out why it's getting stuck in the first place. Is some program running when it happens? Also, when it does get stuck, does clicking on an empty area and then clicking on the taskbar make it go away?